# How can I solve PL/SQL: Statement ignored error?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to write a procedure. The procedure will be queried with the `school number` and the course_name, midterm_not, final_not, the average will be revealed, but the midterm and final grades will be calculated in %. If it is under 60, it will be over and it will be passed.

```
set serveroutput on;
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE student_grade(
        p_school_no IN lessons.school_number%type,
        p_lesson OUT lessons.lesson_name%type,
        p_midterm_1 OUT lessons.midterm_notu_1%type,
        p_midterm_2  OUT lessons.midterm_notu_2%type,
        p_final OUT lessons.final_notu%type,
        p_average OUT NUMBER
    )
    IS
    BEGIN
    SELECT
    d.lesson,
    d.midterm_notu_1,
    d.midterm_notu_2,
    d.final_notu
    INTO
        p_lesson,
        p_midterm_1,
        p_midterm_2,
        p_final
    FROM lessons d
    WHERE d.shool_number = p_school_no
    p_average := (((d.midterm_notu_1 * 25)/100) + ((d.midterm_notu_2 * 30)/100) + ((d.final_notu * 45)/100));
    END;
   
    DECLARE
    v_school_no lessons.school_number%type := 20201754;
    v_lesson lessons.lesson_name%type;
    v_midterm_1 lessons.midterm_notu_1%type;
    v_midterm_2  lessons.midterm_notu_2%type;
    v_final lessons.final_notu%type;
    v_average NUMBER;
    BEGIN
    student_grade(  
        v_lesson,
        v_midterm_1,
        v_midterm_2  ,
        v_final,
        v_average );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Student Grade');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('School Number: ' ||v_school_no);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Midterm 1: ' || v_midterm_1);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Midterm 2: ' || v_midterm_2  );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Final: ' || v_final);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Average: ' || v_average );
    END;
```

I did something like this when I run the procedure it says `"Procedure student_grade compiled"` but when I try to run the `DECLARE` part it gives an error like this;

> ```
> Error report -
> ORA-06550: line 9, column 5:
> PLS-00905: SYSTEM.STUDENT_GRADE object is invalid
> ORA-06550: line 9, column 5:
> PL/SQL: Statement ignored
> 06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
> *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
> ```

I think it has a problem in `p_average :=` 
Can anyone help me with these issues?

Comment: First off, you need to drop that entire procedure, and re-create it in a user schema, NOT in SYSTEM!!!

Comment: @EdStevens Pardon me for asking but I don't know what's the difference between user shema and system.

Comment: System is kind of admin user, normally when we work with a productive database we create necessary user and use the one because system as all necessary privilege where you can do many things in database which could unknowingly create problems.see https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/GUID-CF1CD853-AF15-41EC-BC80-61918C73FDB5.htm#ADMQS12003

Comment: @Ezgi it's like creating a script as root in Linux.

Comment: "user schema" is a schema you create for your application's own objects.  It is usually named something to indicate the application. And it should have its own tablespace.  You do NOT want to create objects under the SYS or SYSTEM schemas, and you do NOT want to place your own object in the SYSTEM tablespace.  Either will lead to all kinds of headaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost done everything fine. Few things with respect to procedure,

Run the below command (may be you over look the part for error)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE student_grade COMPILE;
Warning: Procedure altered with compilation errors
```

---

you do not need to make the `p_average` parameter as IN OUT , OUT should be enough as you calculate it inside.

to assign some value to OUT parameter you don't need to use SET. Only assignment using assignment operator is fine. see below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE student_grade
(
   p_school_no IN lessons.school_number%TYPE
  ,p_lesson    OUT lessons.lesson_name%TYPE
  ,p_midterm_1 OUT lessons.midterm_notu_1%TYPE
  ,p_midterm_2 OUT lessons.midterm_notu_2%TYPE
  ,p_final     OUT lessons.final_notu%TYPE
  ,p_average   OUT NUMBER
) IS
BEGIN
   SELECT d.lesson
         ,d.midterm_notu_1
         ,d.midterm_notu_2
         ,d.final_notu
   INTO   p_lesson
         ,p_midterm_1
         ,p_midterm_2
         ,p_final
   FROM   lessons d
   WHERE  d.shool_number = p_school_no;
   --assign to the output variable for average
   p_average := (((d.midterm_notu_1 * 25) / 100) + ((d.midterm_notu_2 * 30) / 100) + ((d.final_notu * 45) / 100));
END;
/
```

---

I believe because of error exists in procedure you were unable to test, after doing above changes it should work.

You also can test it with a PL/SQL anonymous block instead with SQL command window which would be easier.
E.g.

```
DECLARE
    --assign the input directly here in the declare section
    v_school_no lessons.school_number%type := 10;
    v_lesson lessons.lesson_name%type;
    v_midterm_1 lessons.midterm_notu_1%type;
    v_midterm_2  lessons.midterm_notu_2%type;
    v_final lessons.final_notu%type;
    v_average NUMBER;
BEGIN
    -- call the procedure
    student_grade(  
        v_lesson,
        v_midterm_1,
        v_midterm_2  ,
        v_final,
        v_average );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Student Grade');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('School Number: ' ||v_school_no);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Midterm 1: ' || v_midterm_1);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Midterm 2: ' || v_midterm_2  );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Final: ' || v_final);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Average: ' || v_average );
END;
/
```

Let me know if it solves your problem;

---

### ***REVISED ANSWER WITH SPECIFIC PROBLEM WITH THE USE AND TOOL USAGE***

I strongly recommend/suggests you to look into the documentation of PL/SQL before continue with next assignment. It will help you understanding the errors you get so you can correct it. Also there are many videos on the tool SQL Developer , how to use them efficiently.Check them too.

Coming back to you problem I have tried in my machine and there are many problems to the script which I had to fix one by one looking into the error messages. Please find the points and final solution which should work or else I am done.

Problems: there are differences in names of the column in table with the code you have written

1. `WHERE d.shool_number = p_school_no;` --> shool_number is not an existing column, it is propbably `d.school_number`
2. `v_lesson lessons.lesson_name%type;` --> the actual column is `lesson` and not `lesson_name`. I can say it from your select clause in the procedure
3. `p_lesson OUT lessons.lesson_name%type,` --> same as point 2
4. `p_average := (((d.midterm_notu_1 * 25)/100) + ((d.midterm_notu_2 * 30)/100) + ((d.final_notu * 45)/100));` -- you cannot refer the columns like this , what it means with `"d."` where code doesn't know what it refers. `d` you have used in the select query as alias to table `lessons` and with the select statement ends the scope of `d` finishes there itself. *As you have already taken the values to the output variables such as `p_midterm_1, p_midterm_2, p_final` use them instead*.
5. Additionally make sure the select statement returns only one rows per `school_number=20201754` otherwise you end of with error `ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows` and then there are other ways to handle it. (for the moment I will not say anything with respect to that)
6. Final point where you try to test the procedure like `student_grade( v_lesson, v_midterm_1, v_midterm_2  , v_final, v_average );` --> you are passing wrong number of arguments to the procedure by not including `v_school_no` as the first parameter.

However i have created my own setup and modified the procedure and the test accordingly, see below.

```
--table definition
create table lessons (school_number number,lesson varchar2(100),midterm_notu_1 number,midterm_notu_2 number,final_notu number);
--inserting unique rows per school_number
insert into lessons values(20201754,'Maths',35,55,85);
insert into lessons values(20201755,'Science',45,65,95);

-- to enable the dbms_output
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

--procedure definition
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE student_grade(
        p_school_no IN lessons.school_number%type,
        p_lesson OUT lessons.lesson%type,
        p_midterm_1 OUT lessons.midterm_notu_1%type,
        p_midterm_2  OUT lessons.midterm_notu_2%type,
        p_final OUT lessons.final_notu%type,
        p_average OUT NUMBER
    )
IS
BEGIN
    SELECT
    d.lesson,
    d.midterm_notu_1,
    d.midterm_notu_2,
    d.final_notu
    INTO
        p_lesson,
        p_midterm_1,
        p_midterm_2,
        p_final
    FROM lessons d
    WHERE d.school_number = p_school_no;
    p_average := (((p_midterm_1 * 25)/100) + ((p_midterm_2 * 30)/100) + ((p_final * 45)/100));
END student_grade;
/

--testing the procedure    
DECLARE
    v_school_no lessons.school_number%type := 20201754;
    v_lesson lessons.lesson%type;
    v_midterm_1 lessons.midterm_notu_1%type;
    v_midterm_2  lessons.midterm_notu_2%type;
    v_final lessons.final_notu%type;
    v_average NUMBER;
BEGIN
    student_grade(
        v_school_no,
        v_lesson,
        v_midterm_1,
        v_midterm_2  ,
        v_final,
        v_average );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Student Grade');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('School Number: ' ||v_school_no);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Midterm 1: ' || v_midterm_1);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Midterm 2: ' || v_midterm_2  );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Final: ' || v_final);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Average: ' || v_average );
END;
/
```

Comment: I run the part you said and it gives this error,                                                                   
 `Error starting at line : 190 in command -
Warning: Procedure altered with compilation errors
Error report -
Unknown Command`  When I fix the procedure with what you suggest but it still gives the same error.

Comment: There are two parts, could you run the alter command again and see if it is successful or not. And then the test part. I can update the answer to test via a anonymous PLSQL block. But not sure the exact commands in SQL command window

Comment: I run the alter command and it said  `Procedure student_grade altered.` What do I have to do next? And what is anonymous PLSQL block I don't get it?

Comment: Which means the procedure is valid and ready for testing. When you deal with PL/SQL ,the anonymous block is nothing but combination of `declare begin end`. Now you want to test the procedure using SQL * commands where the way is different to declare first in out variables and then call procedure using `execute student_grade(var1,var2....)`..what you can do now is just copy the code I updated and replace the value for v_school_no to an actual value and then paste it in the SQL command window. Don't forget to do `set serveroutput on` before executing the procedure.

Comment: Learn more about anonymous block https://www.oracletutorial.com/plsql-tutorial/plsql-anonymous-block/

Comment: Did it work ? Are you using SQL developer to run your scripts?

Comment: Yes, I'm using SQL developer for writing my code. I did all of what you said, unfortunately, it didn't work. When I use `ALTER PROCEDURE student_grade COMPILE;` it says `Warning: Procedure altered with compilation errors`.

Comment: Also, I updated my question to be more efficient because it gives a different error now.

Comment: You have said the procedure was fine and you changed again see semicolon misisng in line"WHERE d.shool_number = p_school_no" . Add it. Don't mix two things with one script. Separate and create a procedure and see if it compile without error and then test it with another script.

Comment: @Ezgi: I have updated my answer with the section ***REVISED ANSWER WITH SPECIFIC PROBLEM WITH THE USE AND TOOL USAGE***. please check.

Comment: I'm going to try now but first I'm trying to learn how to create user schema and why it is so important. When I learn about that I'm going to write all my code in the user.

Comment: Having your own schema enables you to create and control your own objects with necessary privileges from DBA ( who has access to sys or system users and all Database controls) . official documentation https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10897/schema.htm#ADMQS12092.. good luck.

Comment: Thank you for helping me but I have one more question about using schema I'm working on my computer alone and it's my practice project should I have to create a user schema? I do everything without using user schema and exporting everything in it could mess up all my work.

Comment: You are right if you have the database in your local system and you can still work with the system user. I believe you have install the XE database from oracle. But using the local database you can create other schema and try out for your knowledge. One more thing from my end ,please don't forget to accept the answer if it has helped you resolving your original question.:)

Comment: Okay, thank you for everything I try your answer and it works fine. :) One more thing if I want to create a new variable in procedure which shows pass or fail results of students with looking at their average. What should I do?

Comment: Without much thought I would suggest to use CASE statement. create another variable var_pass_result varchar2(10) and then var_pass_result := case when p_average <= 35 then 'Fail' when p_average <= 65 then 'Pass' else 'Distinction' end;

Answer (score 0):

The 'accept'  (accept p_school_no prompt ) is a sqlplus directive, not a pl/sql statement.  PL/SQL runs entirely inside the database and has no means of 'accepting' input from the user.  The only means of 'accepting' run-time values is by supplying on the command line when you call the procedure.  That's what those IN parameters are for.

```
exec student_grade('schoolname');
```

Also, 'set'  (SET  p_average := )  is not valid for a SELECT.  It belongs with UPDATE.